# Stopping brute force attempts

Tags: centos, postfix, firewalld, hardening

"postfix/smtpd[28164]: warning: unknown[45.227.253.210]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure"

Normally I'd use fail2ban however it seems that under the openvz container fail2ban and some segments of firewalld do not work properly. Does fine on my dedicated but not the vps setups. I long ago moved SSH off of non standard ports so the attempts are solely aimed at the mail server.

So I guess the question is:

Is there a way to get fail2ban to work under firewalld/Cento 7/OpenVZ vps container or

Is there an alternate way to either stop or throttle these connections.

Seems most of the solutions point towards fail2ban I have had a hard time finding something else that can at least make it difficult to hammer the server such as some throttling mechanisms in postfix itself.

Looking to see what others may suggest.

Comment: Have you thought about trying `smtpd_error_sleep_time` 
 (  i.e. to slow down when a client triggers too many errors ) http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_error_sleep_time ?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like knockd is a viable solution for your problem.  Think of it like a combination lock using ports.

man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/knockd

deprecated but useful tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-your-ssh-daemon-from-attackers-on-ubuntu

another deprecated article that outlines using iptables only: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-port-knocking-using-only-iptables-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: How would `knockd` work for OPs mailserver ?